# How to pass arguments in useContractWrite wagmi

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, react, mint, wagmi

[image]

this is the mint function of my contract and I want to pass the quantity argument, please help me with that. my current code :-
`const { writeAsync: mint, error: mintError } = useContractWrite({ ...contractConfig, functionName: 'mint', });`

and then Iam trying to add arguments this way :-
`const tx = await mint({args: [{_quantity: 1}]});`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tyou dont pass the args to the write function, you pass it in the `useContractWrite` hook like so

```
  const { write: mint } = useContractWrite({
    ...contractConfig,
    functionName: 'mint',
    args: [arg1,arg2,arg3],
  })
```

then call the `mint` function

also the functions you get back from the hook are `{ data, isLoading, isSuccess, write } = useContractWrite({...})` not `error` or `writeAsync`

Comment: Thank you! also I wanted to ask, how can I send the eth value ?

Comment: Never mind ... I got it .... thank you

Comment: To send eth value along with this you have to update the overrides property you pass into the config:
overrides: {
      value: BigNumber.from('10000000000000000'),  
    },